# NPE when activating netty access log and http2

Tags: spring-boot, netty

I want to activate the access log of netty, but it fails with a NPE.

**application.yml**

```
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog: INFO
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
tasks.withType<BootRun> {
  jvmArgs = listOf("-Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true")
}
```

**Problem**

Running the application...

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

...starts up the application but on the first request:

```
2021-04-23 11:54:55.632 ERROR 24889 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [cdc3650c-1] Error [java.lang.NullPointerException] for HTTP GET "/foo/bar?x=1", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)
2021-04-23 11:54:55.638 ERROR 24889 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id:cdc3650c-1, L:/127.0.0.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:60818] Error finishing response. Closing connection

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at reactor.netty.http.server.logging.AccessLogHandlerH1.write(AccessLogHandlerH1.java:102) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.example.FooController#bar(long, CurrentUser, Continuation) [DispatcherHandler]
```

So it seems that `accessLogArgProvider` in `AccessLogHandlerH1` is null, but I could not find what to do about it?

**Notes**

When removing the `jvmArgs` the application works fine. The same problem occurs when using intellij run configurations.

I am on Spring Boot 2.5.0-RC1 and jdk 11.

**UPDATE**

Found out that this issue only occurs with activated http2

```
server.http2.enabled: true
```

In `reactor.netty.http.server.logging` there is a `AccessLogHandlerH1` for http/1.1 and a `AccessLogHandlerH2` for http2.

It seems like the H1 handler is used independently of activating http2 which might be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a bug in reactor-netty: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1610